# Analysis proof of multiplying repeating decimals without converting to fractions

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Consider decimal representations of $\frac 3{11}$ and $\frac{11}3$ and do not convert back to fractions. Multiplying these two together yields $1$ and can be seen by rounding out to $n$ decimal places over and over.
$$\begin{align}3.67\times 0.27&=0.9909\\
3.6667\times 0.2727&=0.99990909\\
3.666667\times 0.272727&=0.99999909\end{align}$$
And as can be seen, rounding out to infinitely many decimals yields one. Is it possible to write an analysis proof of this? I have tried starting this and letting $\epsilon >0$. There exists $N$ such that $\epsilon<\frac 1{10^N}$ but I cannot make much progress past this. Am I on the right track and how do I continue?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to prove that $3.\overline{66} \times 0.\overline{27} = 1$, which can be written as $$\left(3 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {66}{100^n}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac {27}{100^k}\right) = 1$$
So what you are trying to show is
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(3 + \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac {66}{100^n}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac {27}{100^k}\right) = 1$$
If we let $R_N = \sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac 1{100^k}$, this becomes
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}(3 + 66R_N)(27R_N) = \lim_{N\to \infty}81R_N + 1782R_N^2 = 1$$
Let $x = \frac 1{100}$. Then $R_N = \sum_{k=1}^N x^k$. But notice that
$$(1-x)R_N = (1-x)(x + x^2 +\dots +x^N) = x - x^{N+1}\\R_N = \dfrac{x - x^{N+1}}{1-x}$$

Because $x < 1, \lim_{N\to\infty}x^{N+1} = 0$. And $$\lim_{N\to\infty} R_N = \dfrac{x - \lim_{N\to\infty}x^{N+1}}{1-x} = \dfrac{x- 0}{1-x} = \dfrac{\frac 1{100}}{1-\frac 1{100}} = \frac 1{99}$$
Therefore $$\begin{align}\lim_{N\to \infty}(3 + 66R_N)(27R_N) 
&= \lim_{N\to \infty}81R_N + 1782R_N^2\\
&= 81\left(\lim_{N\to \infty} R_N\right) + 1782\left(\lim_{N\to \infty} R_N
\right)^2\\
&= \frac {81}{99} + \frac{1782}{99^2}\\
&=\frac{8019 + 1782}{99^2}\\
&= \frac{9801}{9801}\\ 
&= 1\end{align}$$
as desired.

And, yes, this is an *analytic* proof that the product is $1$. If you want a proof in terms of epsilons instead of limits, you should be more specific. You can back such a proof out of the above, basically replacing the limits with their definitions.